# Is there a better way to return values of a list which are not in the table Sql?

Tags: php, sql, select, subquery

I have a list of numbers like [300420,300421,300422,300423], and a table that has all values from 300000 to 400000(except 300422 and 300423). I need to return the first value from the list that is not in table, now i am using the following code, but it is too slow.

```
foreach ($notas as $tuple) {
    $key = $tuple[0];
    $value = $tuple[1];

    if ($value) {
        $res = $PDO2->query("SELECT DISTINCT Num_Nota FROM itensnfs WHERE Num_Nota='$value'");
        $counter_codes = ($res->rowCount());
        
        if($counter_codes == 0){
            echo "Value " .$value. " don't exist";
            die();          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running. Is this MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enumerate the values in a derived table, and then use `not exists` and aggregation:

```
select min(v.num) num
from (
    select 300420 num
    union all select 300421
    union all select 300422
    union all select 300423
) v
where not exists (select 1 from itensnfs i where i.Num_Nota = v.num)
```

Depending on your database, there are neater alternatives that `union all`  to generate the derived tables.

Some database support row constructor `values()`:

```
select min(v.num) num
from (values (300420), (300421), (300422), (300423)) v(num)
where not exists (select 1 from itensnfs i where i.Num_Nota = v.num)
```

MySQL is a notable exception - but very recent versions support `values row()`:

```
select min(v.num) num
from (values row (300420), row (300421), row (300422), row (300423)) v(num)
where not exists (select 1 from itensnfs i where i.Num_Nota = v.num)
```